# How to determine which direction a machine is moving given all its positional data using Python?

Tags: python, numpy

**Question Explanation:**

I have a fairly large file(up to 1 million lines) containing data from a mining machine. The data includes the X and Y coordinates of the machine. The machine should only be able to mine to the left (-X direction) or to the right (+X direction) and this occurs in a 'lane'. It should not be able to mine the same area again, but it can change Y-coordinates at any time(i.e, it can change lanes at any time) and skip certain areas. I want to determine in which direction the machine is moving at a given time. For example I want to see where the machine is moving to the left or to the right. Although this sounds simple enough, I am having a bit of trouble.

**My attempt:**

I am currently finding the sum of 100 values of the difference array of the X-coordinates (the difference array gives the distance the machine has moved). Ideally, if the X-coordinates are decreasing in a 100 point interval, then it should be moving to the left, and if the X-coordinates were increasing in that interval, it should be moving to the right. So if the sum was negative, it will append "0" to an array 100 times.  I chose 100 because I thought it would be fairly accurate considering the high number of samples.

```
# miner_x = array of the x-coordinates of the machine
# miner_x_diff = numpy.diff(miner_x)
# 0 = Negative X direction
# 1 = Positive X direction

diffSample= [sum(miner_x_diff[i:i+100]) for i in range(0, len(miner_x_diff), 100)]
Direction = np.array([])
for value in diffSample:
    if value < 0:
        for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 100):
           Direction = np.append(Direction,0)
    else:
        for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 100):
            Direction = np.append(Direction,1)
# correct size 
if Direction.size > miner_x.size:
    Direction = Direction[0:Direction.size-(Direction.size-miner_x.size)]
```

The problem I am having is at the point it changes direction from left to right or vice versa, and this mostly occurs during a lane change. This if course expected, since the sum around that area could be close to 0. But I am not sure how to go about accounting for this change using my current method. Is there a more accurate way to determine the direction of the machine?

An example of a plot of the machines position using one particular data set is shown below (code omitted because it is unnecessary). The yellow points are positions where I had incorrect results occur .In this example there shouldn't be any yellow points. I have not shown the direction color in this example but you can of course see it if I say the start position is at the bottom right.
[image: Position of the machine]

I will appreciate any help/advice/hints :)

**Edit:**
Here is a picture of what I want (mind the Paint skills). Note that I don't want to 'see' a straight line, just to know that it is moving in those directions at those points. Green is the start point.
[image: desired result]

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your problem. do you want to get all direction changes?

Comment: I want to know when it is moving left or right, so yes all all direction changes. For example, looking at the plot above, if the start position was at the bottom right (roughly X = 40025, Y = -58587), then I want to know that it is moving left until it reaches that lane end,and then once it changes direction I want it to know that it is moving right, and so on..I know this can easily be seen from the plot, but I want to record the direction (left or right) next to the the positional data. Sorry if I explained that badly, I tried my best.

Comment: You should be able to spot direction changes as sign change in your diff array. If the input data is noisy there may be false positives. In that case you can filter the array using some of the filtering routines in scipy.signal. For simple data like this one, the median filter or a  Savitzky-Golay filter (scipy.signal.savgol, which is a 3rd order polynomial fitting) might do the trick. If you want to use low-pass filtering routines you can also use filtfilt, which does not cause phase delays.

Comment: Ok thank you I will have a look into those :)

Answer (score 1):

Start by using a smaller sample window. How much time is represented by 100 sample points? The interval should be small enough that you can simply look at the displacement between the initial and final position and have a direction for that time segment. (You do realize that summing the difference of consecutive pairs of numbers is the same as subtracting the first from the last number, don't you?) If you catch the machine at a point where it's turning around, you may get indeterminate data but the samples before and after will show a straight vector.

Comment: One sample point is taken every 4 seconds. The reason I can't really use very small intervals is because the data is noisy. For example, the machine could be moving to the left according two consecutive points , but due to drift and other factors the next points will show it's moving to the right, but it' still actually moving to the left along that line. I  didn't realize that summing the difference of consecutive pairs of numbers is the same as subtracting the first from the last number, but now I do, thanks. Yes, that is the problem I am having: during the turn around/lane change.

Comment: Makes sense. But if the machine can really turn around several times in a 400 second window (6.6 minutes), then reduce the window to e.g. 10 samples. You can also take a moving average, not disjoint slices, so that you have more data points but less jiggle between them.

Comment: But I admit I'm not clear what you want; what DO you want to see during the turnaround? You know it's turning around periodically, you know what its trajectory looks like at these points.

Comment: I have added a picture to show I want. Not that that when the machine changes position (such as moving to a new lane), it lifts off the ground and no data is recorded till it is placed back (this is an assumption). Anyway, sorry to confuse you. As suggested by Ben, I will first filter the data. I will then take into account a lane change (big change in Y coordinate). So for each 'lane' I will perform the direction check, so I won't have that previous problem when it's changing directions.